# How to load partial images like instagram?

Tags: html, ajax

I am sorry that I am not sure what keywords should be used for searching the answer.

My situation now is...
Assume that now I have more than hundreds of images needed to be loaded
I hope the users just load first ten images,
after scrolling to the bottom, the site will then download another ten images

I should be using ajax? some array to store the hundreds of images? and??

Comment: Use pagination and then infinite scroll to achieve what you're trying to do. However you haven't detailed what platform you are using, or even included any code, so it is difficult to work out what it is you exactly need